# how to Store IP Address to Variable when user enter IP Address in prompt box.?

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to phoneGap and I'm using navigator.notification.prompt in my code. I want to add IP Address (192.168.1.201) in prompt box, the added IP address should save to new variable and also check for that variable is null or not. Here is my code:

```
function config()
{    
    var ret =navigator.notification.prompt("Server Address : ",click me,"Server IP",["Ok","Cancel"],"");

    if (ret =='')
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Plz enter the correct Ip Address");   
    }
    else
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Ip address is saved for your mobile"
            localStorage.setItem("ipAddress",ret);
    }
}

function clickme()
{
    navigator.notification.alert("Ip address is saved for your mobile", null, "Server IP", "OK");
}
```

but I'm not able to save the entered IP address to variable return and check for that variable is null or not. please help me in sorting out this problem

Comment: `setItem()` returns null. break it up or use `localStorage.key=` access to take advantage of JS's leaky assignments.

Comment: @dandavis whatever i will enter, that value is not getting save to ret variable and after that i want to validate ret variable .

Comment: thanks for suggestion @dandavis but localStorage.key is not working

Comment: from the code above you need to replace (exactly) `localStorage.setItem("ipAddress",ret);` with `localStorage.ipAddress=ret);` you can use `ret` anywhere inside the `config()` function.

Comment: @dandavis that is not my problem .when i enter IP Address in prompt box(navigator.notification.prompt) the entered value is not storing into variable ret. If i use simple prompt then entered value value will store to ret variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use prompt in the following way...

```
function config() {
        navigator.notification.prompt(
            'Server Address : ',  // message
            onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
            'Server IP',            // title
            ['Ok','cancel']              // buttonLabels
        );
    }

function onPrompt(results) {
        if (results.input1 =='')
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Plz enter the correct Ip Address");   
    }
    else
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Ip address is saved for your mobile");
            localStorage.setItem("ipAddress",results.input1);
    }
    }
```

if you want to get ip address use

```
function getIp(){
 localStorage.getItem("ipAddress");
}
```

Comment: if i want to validate whether the enter IP address is correct or not . I'm using this code is( results.input1==

Comment: (results.input1 =='^((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$')this code is not working for me . This IP address 192.168.1.112 i want to validate. Please help me

Comment: function ValidateIPaddress(ipaddress)   
{  
 if (/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(ipaddress))  
  {  
    return (true)  
  }  
alert("You have entered an invalid IP address!")  
return (false)  
}

Comment: @nareshi don't know where to put this function in my code,so i don't want another function.In function onPrompt , if the user entered IP address is not valid then its has to display else part of the alert.

Answer (score 0):

complete answer with validation

```
function config() {
        navigator.notification.prompt(
            'Server Address : ',  // message
            onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
            'Server IP',            // title
            ['Ok','cancel']              // buttonLabels
        );
    }

function onPrompt(results) {
        if (/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?‌​)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)‌​$/.test(results.input1)) 
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Plz enter the valid Ip Address");   
    }
    else
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Ip address is saved for your mobile");
            localStorage.setItem("ipAddress",results.input1);
    }
    }
```

Comment: its not working .Im geeting only else part of alert msg if i give correct or incorrecct IP Address

Comment: bro come to hangouts my mail id is naresh.k.suruvu@gmail.com